# Signal a specific pthread with a condition

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, semaphore, openbsd

I'm working with pthreads and semaphores, and I'm trying to figure out how to signal a *specific* thread.

The thread I want to signal with a certain condition will be the thread that was waiting at the head of my queue.

The main chunk of my **semaphore.h** file is:

```
struct entry_thread {
    int threadID;
    SIMPLEQ_ENTRY(entry_thread) next;
} *np;

struct semaphore {
    int count;
    int headThreadID;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t flag;
    SIMPLEQ_HEAD(queuehead, entry_thread) head;
};

typedef struct semaphore semaphore_t;
```

And the related parts of my **semaphore.c** file are:

```
void down( semaphore_t* sem )
{

    pthread_mutex_lock( &sem->mutex );
    while ( sem->count <= 0)
    {
        // First check if queue is empty, if so, set a new headThreadID
        if (SIMPLEQ_EMPTY( &(sem->head) ))
        {
            sem->headThreadID = pthread_self();
        }
        np = malloc( sizeof( struct entry_thread ) );
        np->threadID = pthread_self();
        SIMPLEQ_INSERT_TAIL( &(sem->head), np, next);
        pthread_cond_wait( &sem->flag, &sem->mutex );
    }
    sem->count--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &sem->mutex );
}

void up( semaphore_t* sem )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &sem->mutex );
    sem->count++;
    if ( sem->count == 1 )
    {
        // Get the head of the semaphore's queue
        SIMPLEQ_REMOVE_HEAD( &(sem->head), (np = SIMPLEQ_FIRST(&(sem->head))), next );

        /* I WANT TO ONLY SIGNAL THE HEAD THREAD!!! */
        pthread_cond_signal( &sem->flag );
        /* THE ABOVE SIGNALS A RANDOM SINGLE THREAD */

        free( np );
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &sem->mutex );
}
```

So my issue is that even though I can get a thread's ID, I need to be able to signal that thread that the condition it is waiting on has changed and it can test the semaphore again. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of advice should be, *always* check the return value from calls to lock mutex, as well as condition API functions.

While everything is okay, omitting return value checks works fine, but when it goes wrong, the whole system comes down in such a way that makes it impossible to debug, or trace the source of the problem.

The idea behind `pthread_cond_signal` waking a random, single thread is thus: In a multi-threaded application, your tasks are not dependant on the order of execution. When you have X threads waiting on the same condition, it is assumed that any of them can run when the condition is signalled.

*In general different threads doing different things, should be waiting on different conditions.*

Your code seems to only ever insert one thread into the queue, it's not really a queue.

Your use of `pthread_cond_wait` does not include checking a (meaningful) predicate, if you're not sure why you need a predicate, do some research. If the predicate is supposed to be that `while` then I think there are logical errors in your code.

Once your queue is being populated correctly with all threads that are waiting for cpu time, you could swap `pthread_cond_signal` for `pthread_cond_broadcast` and make the predicate for `pthread_cond_wait` a flag to determine if the current thread is the thread being scheduled. I assume that you then need to wake the other threads that are waiting in the correct order, some how ...

This is not the best implementation I can imagine for a scheduler, but it's close to your attempt. You should get it working, then see if you can improve upon it by determining what it's performance characteristics are, and what they should be.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I appreciate you letting me know what I'm doing wrong, this is part of an assignment from my OS course and I'm extremely new to C, so I really do need to learn best-practices. What the task here is supposed to emulate is creating our own scheduling algorithm, and the one in the assignment is that the first thread added to a semaphore's queue should be the one notified when the condition it is waiting on has changed. So the priority of each thread is whether or not it is at the head of the queue. With this information, do you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the updates. So I believe that I may have solved my problem by adding an extra condition to the `down()` function's while loop guard. There I also now check if `sem->headThreadID != pthread_self()`, and if so the pthread will go back to waiting. In my `up()` function, I dequeue the first element in the queue, check if another element is in the queue, and if there is one, I set `sem->headThreadID` to be that thread's ID.